# while orientation is vertical only one field is display in a row

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I'm using vertical orientation for my app. But I want to display more than 1 field in single row. Is it possible? I want display the Buttons in single row instead of single column.

[image: in image buttons are placed 1 after 1 in single column. i need it in single row.]

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/bMultiply"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:onClick="addMultiply"
android:text="@string/bMultiply" />
```

sample for button config in activity_Calc_main.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                 android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView ....
    <TextView   .....

    <LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button ...
    <Button ...
    <Button ...
    <Button ...

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When I try android:orientation="horizontal" all fields shows in single row including edittext,buttons,TextView.

Comment: You can use android:orientation="horizontal" only for area where you want Buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Do the followings

```
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical" >
     // add other elements on top of the buttons
     <LinearLayout
         android:orientation="horizontal" >
         //add buttons here

     </LinearLayout>

     // add other elements on bottom of the buttons
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout ...
    android:orientation="vertical">
 <EditText...../>
 <EditText...../>
 <LinearLayout ...
    android:orientation="horizontal"> <-----

    <Button.../>
    <Button.../>
    <Button.../>
    <Button.../>

 </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```